# Date format conversion issue

Tags: php, date

I have an issue that I have been dealing for way to long

Please look at the code below: ( I have commented on the right the values that I get when I debug the variable)

When input is for example "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

```
 $date1 = ($date['confirmed_at']); //value of $date1 is "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
 $date2 = strtotime($date1); //value of $date2 is "1"
 $date3 = date('y-m-d',$date2); //value of $date3 is "70-01-01"
```

When input is for example "2011-09-12 08:57:26"

```
 $date1 = ($date['confirmed_at']); //value of $date1 is "2011-09-12 08:57:26"
 $date2 = strtotime($date1); //value of $date2 is "1315817846"
 $date3 = date('y-m-d',$date2); //value of $date3 is "11-09-12"
```

I'm a bit confused with the values that I have been getting...
All that I am trying to do is take the date which is currently in a **"YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS" and convert it into a "YYYY-MM-DD" format.**

Comment: Beware: `strtotime` can not represent dates prior to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT.  Day 0 of year 0 AD is a few thousand years prior.  If you need to represent dates prior to 1970, you should use a [DateTime](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).  Otherwise, a simple error check after the `strtotime` call is all you need here.  Oh, and use a *capital* Y to get a four digit year.

Comment: all of the dates that I'm trying to get are those from around 2-3 years ago...the only trouble that I've been having is with the ones that look like this 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing in the first example results from the fact, that `strtotime()` returns a unix timestamp,  that is a number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970. It just can't return anything sensible for `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

For `YYYY-MM-DD` format use `date('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 0):

use "date('Y-m-d',$date2)" for the YYYY-MM-DD format

Answer (score 0):

The result of `strtotime("0000-00-00 00:00:00")` may varies by PHP version and OS, so use `strtotime` for zero date `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"` makes no sense.